# Desingularization of the zero section of $TM$ as the manifold of singularities of the geodesic flow

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems, singularity-theory, resolution-of-singularities

However the method of  "Blowing up of   singularities" is  initially introduced for  an isolated singularity, but this  method have  been  generalized to  blowing up of  a  "Manifold of  singularities", say "curve of  singularities",  "surface  of  singularities", etc.

This  method  is  applied in the  following  paper (and some of  its  references) which  contains  a counter example  to  an  open  conjecture on the  number of  limit  cycles of  Lienard  equation.

https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2007-135-06/S0002-9939-07-08688-1/S0002-9939-07-08688-1.pdf

So desingularisation of  a  manifold of  singularities, instead of  an isolated singularity,   can  have very  strong  consequences(giving  a  counter example  to  a  conjecture or  some  other interesting  consequences).

This  situation is a  motivation to  ask the  following  question about  an  arbitrary  Riemannian   manifold  $M$:

> What  would be    some  consequences and  results   of  blowing up  of  the  zero  section, as the singular set of the  geodesic  flow  on $TM$? Are  there some papers  or book devoting  to this  point of  view?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "blowing up of the zero section, as the singular set of the geodesic flow on TM"? Blowing up is interesting only if the manifold is singular (for example, a cone) and you blow up the singularity, Your question appears to be about a smooth manifold without any singularities. Also, what role does the geodesic flow play in the the blow up? Note that the geodesic flow is also a smooth flow. It's just stationary along the zero section.

Comment: @DeaneYangMy apology for my delay. By  blowing up  I  mean  the  blow-up of a  singular point  of  a  vector  field: For  an isolated  singular point of  a  vector  field   $X$ at  origin in $\mathbb{R}^n$,  we  define  a  map $p:S^{n-1}\times \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^n$  with  $p(z,t)=tz$. Then  we  pull back the  vector  field  X  to  a  vector  field on $S^{n-1}\times \mathbb{R}$. the resulting field vanishs  at  $S^{n-1}\times{0}$. Then we  factor out a term $t^k$ for  some $k$. This process is called  blowing up of the  isolated singularity at origin. THE  word  singular indicates that we

Comment: have  a  singularity of  a  vector  field, not  singularity of  manifold. As  a  generalization of this  process, in  a  paper by  R. Roussarie  and F. Dumortier, Memoir  AMS(The  refrence [1] of  the  linked paper , they apply the  process for the  case of  a  curve  of singularity or  a  manifold  of  singularity. This  methods  leads  to a  blow  up interpretation of the  concept of  CANARD.Now  in geodesic flow, the  zero section is a  manifold of  singularity for the  geodesic  flow.